# Binding MS Reporting Services

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report, reportviewer, rdlc

I cannot bind the report (rdlc) with a dataset that I am creating programmatically from web forms.

Sample binding:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>();
    customerList.Add(new Customer{ CustomerID = 1, CustomerName = "1654184185"});
    customerList.Add(new Customer { CustomerID = 2, CustomerName = "sdfsdfsdfs" });
    customerList.Add(new Customer { CustomerID = 3, CustomerName = "dsdfsrtertertdf" });

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report.rdlc";
    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1_Customers_DataTable1", customerList);
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
}
```

Report viewer:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Height="720px" Width="787px">
    <LocalReport ReportEmbeddedResource="Report.rdlc">
        <DataSources>
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource />
        </DataSources>
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

The report itself is not loading as I cannot see the static texts in the reportviewer also. I am following [articles](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31862/Dynamic-Binding-Of-RDLC-To-ReportViewer) but still the same. But if I use just GUI and drag n drop `ObjectDataSource` then report shows up but I need to pass filtered versions of the dataset at different times. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report was not even being shown because I did not make a `IsPostBack` check after adding it inside `PageLoad` everything worked fine.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>();
        customerList.Add(new Customer{ CustomerID = 1, CustomerName = "1654184185"});
        customerList.Add(new Customer { CustomerID = 2, CustomerName = "sdfsdfsdfs" });
        customerList.Add(new Customer { CustomerID = 3, CustomerName = "dsdfsrtertertdf" });

        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report.rdlc";
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1_Customers_DataTable1", customerList);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
    }
}
```